# How to import big data of .dat format in a fast way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to import a `.dat` file into Python using the `PyGeostat` library. The file contains `geoeas` data and is about 5 GB in size.

output_Back

```
 2  
VALUES                                   
Back   
    -99.0000  0.0000000    
    -99.0000  0.0000000    
    -99.0000  0.0000000
```

.
.
.

```
import pygeostat as gs

datafile = gs.DataFile("somefile.dat")
```

However, when I run the code, I get a memory error. I have tried increasing the RAM memory allocated to Python, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can import large `.dat` files with `PyGeostat` or another Python library? I have tried using the `h5py` library to convert the file to `HDF5` format, it takes 5 hours and I have not been able to progress.

Note: there are 2 columns **values** and **Back**

Answer (score 0):

You can't fit all this data directly at once; you will need to break it into pieces and iterate over them like you do with batch training.
The size of a chunk is specified using the chunksize parameter, which refers to the number of lines.

```
pd.read_csv('somefile.dat',sep=" ", chunksize=100000).
```

Process each chunk independently, performing necessary operations and storing relevant results.
Aggregate or combine results from individual chunks as needed.

Code Example

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('somefile.dat.csv', chunksize=10000):
    # do whatever you want with the chunk (e.g., filter, calculate statistics)
```

More over here.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

## 1-Alternative solution 'desk'

you will need to install 'desk' then just  use it to read you csv file.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('your_file.dat',delimiter=' ', header=None)
```

## 2-Alternative solution (not recommnded)

you can Access data directly from disk without loading the entire file into memory using `mmap`  (don't try this if you don't have fast ssd)

Code Example:

```
import mmap

with open('somefile.dat', 'r') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    data = mm.read().decode('utf-8')  
    # process data here
    mm.close()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

Recommended article about using `chunks` and `desk`.
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/optimized-ways-to-read-large-csvs-in-python-ab2b36a7914e